# plot number of samples on a boxplot with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am using `matplotlib` to plot a boxplot as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

x1 = np.random.randint(0, 101, size=10).tolist()
x2 = np.random.randint(0, 101, size=20).tolist()

labels = ('Data10', 'Data20')

plt.boxplot((x1, x2))
plt.xticks(range(1, len(labels) + 1), labels, rotation='vertical')
```

Now, what I want to do is also be able to print the number of observations on top of each of these boxplots. Is there any easy way to do that using `matplotlib`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No other way in matplotlib than to use annotations.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

x1 = np.random.randint(0, 101, size=10).tolist()
x2 = np.random.randint(0, 101, size=20).tolist()

labels = ('Data10', 'Data20')

plt.boxplot((x1, x2))
plt.xticks(range(1, len(labels) + 1), labels, rotation='vertical')
ax = plt.gca() # get current axis object
ax.annotate('local max', xy=(.5, .5),  xycoords='axes fraction',
        xytext=(0.2, 0.95), textcoords='axes fraction')
```

Comment: This only annotates one of the boxplot and not the second one.

Comment: Annotations are not connected to your data. They are addiotional patches in the graph. You add as many as you need. In your case, you need two of course. I have just included one so that you can see how to use it.